# Stress tensor for a real massive vector field in General Relativity

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, field-theory, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, variational-calculus

Let's consider the classical Lagrangian density for a real vector field $A_\mu$,
$$
\mathcal{L}_v=\sqrt{-g}\left(-\frac{1}{2}A_{\mu;\alpha}A^{\mu; \alpha}-\frac{1}{2} R_{\mu \nu} A^\mu A^\nu+\frac{1}{2%
}m^2A_{\mu }A^{\mu }\right),
$$
with the gauge condition
$$
A^\mu_{;\mu}=0.
$$
I'm trying to find the analytical form of stress tensor as follows
$$ T_{\mu\nu}=\frac{2}{\sqrt{-g}} \frac{\delta \mathcal{L}_v}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}=-g_{\mu\nu}\mathcal{L} +2\frac{\delta\mathcal{L}}{\delta g_{\mu\nu}}$$
So after variation using Palatini identity and the gauge condition I obtain
$$
T_{\mu\nu}= A_{\alpha;\mu}A^\alpha_{;\nu}+g_{\alpha\beta} A^{;\alpha}_{\mu}A^{;\beta}_{\nu}-\frac{1}{2}m^2 A_\mu A_{\nu}-g_{\mu \nu} \mathcal{L}.
$$
Is that correct? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Welcome to Physics! Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.